# Edit specific text on a static page

Tags: customization, static-website

I'm kinda stuck with my Wordpress development. I must say, I'm a noob at this right now but trying to get more knowledge of this.

In Wordpress admin, there is this text editor for editing the content on a static page. (in my case)  On this static page I've got, I have several div's which contain content.

My question is, can I update the text in these div's separately in the text editor? If so, how can i achieve this?

I have already been looking in the codex, but I'm not really able to find the right solution for what I'm trying to achieve. Any answer will be highly appreciated.
(I know I did not post any code, I'm just looking for a direction to go)

Answer (score 1):

The [WordPress built-in editor](http://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/content/editors/) supports two editing modes, "Visual" and "Text."

The "Text" mode allows you to directly edit the actual HTML of the page (or post), including any `<div>` elements that might be there.